# Criando um .BAT e executando o codigo com privilegios de administrador

Tags: prompt

Como faço uma .bat e executo e linha do código como ADM diretamente via código ?

Comment: Não da, você precisa gerar o BAT e clicando nele com o botão direito vá em configurações na aba compatibilidade marque a caixa "executar como administrador" e aplique assim esse bat será executado como administrador em qualquer windows. [API da MICROSOFT](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/2782915)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infelizmente, não há um comando para elevar os privilégios no Windows, como um `sudo` no Unix, mas é possível sim. Logo abaixo, vou colocar o código com mais votos desta [outra pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-administrator):

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Elevate.cmd - Version 4
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:init
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set cmdInvoke=1
set winSysFolder=System32
set "batchPath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO **************************************

ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"

if '%cmdInvoke%'=='1' goto InvokeCmd 

ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
goto ExecElevation

:InvokeCmd
ECHO args = "/c """ + "!batchPath!" + """ " + args >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\cmd.exe", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"

:ExecElevation
"%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
setlocal & cd /d %~dp0
if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM Run shell as admin (example) - put here code as you like
ECHO %batchName% Arguments: P1=%1 P2=%2 P3=%3 P4=%4 P5=%5 P6=%6 P7=%7 P8=%8 P9=%9
cmd /k
```

No caso, é só colocar o seu próprio script a partir do ponto onde está `REM Run shell as admin (example) - put here code as you like`

Comment: Obrigado Dudakank!
Rodei a internet inteira e só vc conseguiu me ajudar.
Obrigado por dispor um pouco do seu tempo para nos ajudar!