# Cmd admin para não admin

Tags: prompt

Eu vi nesse link que é possível mudar pra adm no win7.
<sub>[Criando um .BAT e executando o codigo com privilegios de administrador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256156/criando-um-bat-e-executando-o-codigo-com-privilegios-de-administrador?newreg=1fe6b73eb9c34e71b81a6b62d8c920c5)</sub>

Porem queria saber como muda de volta pra ninguém perceber que toda a hora que abrir ele normal vai aparecer Admin

```bsh
@echo off

:init
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set cmdInvoke=1
set winSysFolder=System32
set "batchPath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO **************************************

ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"

if '%cmdInvoke%'=='1' goto InvokeCmd 

ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
goto ExecElevation

:InvokeCmd
ECHO args = "/c """ + "!batchPath!" + """ " + args >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\cmd.exe", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"

:ExecElevation
"%SystemRoot%\%winSysFolder%\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
setlocal & cd /d %~dp0
if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)

REM Run shell as admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicando, o que aconteceu versus o que você viu...

***Eu vi nesse link que é possível mudar pra adm no win7.***

- Não, você não viu isso, o que você viu foi apenas a execução de um código que verifica se o usuário que o invocou é um usuário com credencial de administrador ou um membro desse grupo, e caso este usuário não for (não tiver essa credencial), vai solicitar uma permissão elevada de um usuário que a tenha (administrador/ou outro pertencente ao grupo de administradores), para só depois dar seguimento nas execuções ao nível de um permissionamento elevado de administrador, mas se caso esse usuário não tenha tal credencial, ele finaliza imediatamente sem dar continuidade na execução, que obrigatoriamente requer esse permissionamento na sua execução:

```
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL 
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )``
```

- É o mesmo que testar e comportar-se:`

```
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL 
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ('tenho privilégios') else ('obter privilégios')
 
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' tenho privilégios' == '0' sou adminstrador

if '%errorlevel%' ≠  '0' obter privilégios == preciso ser adminstrador // ou ter aprovação de um
```

---

***Porem queria saber como muda de volta pra ninguém perceber que toda a hora que abrir ele normal vai aparecer Admin***

**1.** Seja o administrador ou um usuário membro desse grupo

**2.** Adicione um script no gerenciador de tarefas já adicionando sua credencial para as execuções agendando as execuções necessárias conforme a necessidade

**3.** Entenda que sem atender os itens **1** & **2**, a execução não será possível, visto que não existe código que possa ***"promover o usuário sem status de administrador"*** para um usuário com o ***status de administrador***.